# QuerySet por mes de creación

Tags: python, django

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy usando un `queryset` para mostrar los datos en una tabla indicando los registros creados en cada mes y cuantos de ellos son hombres y cuantos son mujeres.

Este es mi modelo:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
('', _('')),
('M', _("Masculino")),
('F', _("Femenino")),
('O', _("otro")))

class PersonaBase(models.Model):
    # Otros atributos
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=False,
                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES, verbose_name=_("genero"))

class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Simpatizante(TimeStampedModel, PersonaBase):
    # Otros atributos
```

Estoy usando la siguiente sentencia:

```
num_simpatizates_meses_qs = Simpatizante.objects.values('fecha_creacion', 'genero') \
    .annotate(num_simpatizantes_meses=Count('fecha_creacion')) \
    .annotate(hombres_simpatizantes_meses=Count(Case(When(genero='M',
                                                         then=(Simpatizante.objects.filter(genero='M').count()))))) \
    .annotate(mujeres_simpatizantes_meses=Count(Case(When(genero='F',
                                                         then=(Simpatizante.objects.filter(genero='F').count()))))) \
    .filter(campana_electoral=campana_electoral).order_by('-fecha_creacion')
```

Trate de hacerlo usando un `@property` en el modelo simpatizante pero no funciono:

```
@property
def mes_fecha_creacion(self):
    return self.fecha_creacion.strftime("%B")
```

Actualmente obtengo un listado con el `datetime` de creación de cada uno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito mostrarlo agrupado por meses, Enero, Febrero, Marzo, etc.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar

Comment: De manera simple, puedes hacer un group by Meses[5:6] y count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente forma:

```
num_simpatizates_meses_qs = Simpatizante.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('fecha_creacion')) \
    .annotate(year=ExtractYear('fecha_creacion')) \
    .values('month').annotate(num_simpatizantes_meses=Count('id')).order_by()
```

Y con la siguiente linea obtengo el nombre del mes correspondiente:

```
calendar.month_name[mes['month']]
```

Donde `mes['month']` es el numero correspondiente al mes que necesito